# Prompting for input in post-install script in dpkg

Tags: shell-script, prompt, dpkg

I am writing a debian package and need to prompt the user for some textual details(default password, etc), as well as some one-of-many choices("Pick one of the following: foo, bar"). Will shell scripts run in dpkg use `read` or `select` correctly, or do I need another solution? If so, please point me to a quick guide about it.

Comment: @UlrichDangel Could you add an asnwer so I can accept it?

Comment: @UlrichDangel A Stackoverflow meta search turns up results that they are on topic here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not use read, select or dialog yourself but use [debconf](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=debconf&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&locale=) instead which supports readline, dialog, gtk and even web frontends. This is much more flexible than your own system. If you are using [dh](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%20testing%20%28wheezy%29&format=html&locale=en) for building your system it will automatically use [dh_installdebconf](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dh_installdebconf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) and you'll just have to place your template in `debian/package.config` and don't have to adjust/modify your `debian/rules` file or postinst script.

For a short introduction into debconf have a look at [The Debconf Programmer's Tutorial](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html).

Comment: The tutorial linked is very useful, however the example code does not work ("db_input medium" needs to be changed to "db_input high", otherwise the question is not shown to the user). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/473453/deb-package-shell-script-with-debconf-does-not-show-input-dialog

Comment: Thanks @Étienne with your hint I finally managed to run the [tutorial](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html) sample code.